# HEROKU- Application error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have my heroku app, i was working on it today and suddenly the page give me `application error` when i checked logs i saw as follows:

```
2014-05-01T16:21:22.016863+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2014-05-01T16:21:22.017058+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2014-05-01T16:21:25.617019+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-05-01 16:21:25] FATAL SignalException: SIGTERM
```

**How to change state from down to up ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this question just one line command :

```
 heroku ps:restart web.1
```